# Why can a docker container still write to a mounted volume if the host folder is deleted?

Tags: linux, docker

Why can a container still write to a mounted volume if the host folder is deleted?

The process running in the container is opening a new file in a folder on the host. It does not fail when the folder on the host is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If the folder on the host computer is deleted, the process running in the container can still write to the mounted volumes because it has a PID on the host. this means it still has permission to read and write the folder on the host machine, no matter if the folder has been deleted or not.

ypu can use a volume driver that supports shared storage. This allows multiple containers to access the same data, allowing the data to persist even if the folder on the host is deleted.

Look into

- Docker Volume Drivers: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/
- Container Storage Fundamentals: https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/